# Moving from Relational Database to Big Data

Tags: mysql, performance, google-cloud-platform, analytics, bigdata

Currently I have an application hosted on the Google Cloud Platform that offers web analytics and provides session activity (clicks, downloads etc) and ties that web activity with web registrations.

At the moment we store all of our click and session profile data in MySQL and use SQL queries to generate both aggregate and per-user reports, however, as the amount of data has grown, we are seeing a real slow-down in query responses which is in turn slowing down page-load times.

In investigating ways we can solve this problem, we have looked into tools available on Google Cloud Platform like Dataproc and Dataflow as well as NoSQL solutions, however, I am having a hard time understanding how we could apply our current solution to any of these solutions.

Currently, a rough idea of our data schema is as follows:

```
User table
- id
- name
- email

Profile table (web browser/device)
- id
- user id
- user agent string

Session table
- id
- profile id
- session string

Action table
- id
- session id
- action type
- action details
- timestamp
```

Based on my research, my understanding of what would be the best solution would be to store action data in a NoSQL database solution like BigTable which feeds data into a solution like DataProc or DataFlow which generates the reports. However, given that our current schema is a highly relational structure, seems to remove the option of moving towards a NoSQL solution as all my research indicates that you shouldn't move relational data to a NoSQL solution.

My question is, is my understanding of how to apply these tools correct? Or are there better solutions? Is it even necessary to consider moving away from MySQL? And if not, what kind of solutions are available that would allow us to possibly pre-process/generate reporting data in the background?

Comment: Are session and actions table values are updated? I mean are those inserts only or are there updates as well?

Comment: Session table gets updated via a cronjob that aggregates some data such as action-count per session into the session table, however, actions are insert-only.

Comment: You can keep a temp sessions table in MySQL and once the session is finished or at the end of the day dump it all into BigQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `sessions` and `actions` table values are not updated and only insert. The best way would be to separate the databases into two parts. Keep the MySQL DB for `user` and `profile` tables and use the [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) for `actions` and `sessions`.

This way you have following:

- minimize the amount of change you have to do on the either sides (data ingestion and extraction)
- you will significantly reduce the cost of data storage
- query times will significantly improve
- before you know it, you will be in the big data territory and BigQuery is just the solution for it

BigQuery is the best way. But, if you have too many extra resources and time available, you can look into storing it into NoSQL db, then run a pipeline job on it using DataFlow to extract analytics data which you will again need to store in a database for querying purposes.

Comment: The cherry on top: You can partition your BigQuery tables on the date and reduce the cost of long-term storage as well as everyday queries.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of questions / potential solutions:

1. Profile! If it's the same queries thrashing the database, then optimising your queries or caching some of the results for your most frequent pages can help offload processing. Ditto for database settings, RAM, etc.
2. How big is your database? If it's less than 64GB, scaling up to a larger server where the database can fit into RAM could be a quick win.
3. How is your data being used? If it's purely for historical data, you could potentially reduce your clicks down into a lookup table, eg. actions per session per week or per user per week. If the data is collated per 5 minutes / hour, downloading the raw data and processing it like this locally can work too.
4. You can denormalise, eg. combine user agent|session|action type|details|timestamp into one row, but you potentially increase your storage requirements and lookup time.
5. Alternatively, more normalisation can help too. Breaking out the user agent string into its own table will reduce that table's data requirements and might speed things up.
6. It seems like your data might be able to be split up / sharded by user, so that could be another option.

In general, the fastest way to work these questions out is to give it a try for your specific workloads, eg. how many of your typical requests (or random dashboards) can you do on a development machine with a reasonable amount of RAM (or spin up a server/create a different test database).

Also, if you're mostly used to relational databases, there'll be some overhead in switching (particularly for bleeding edge solutions), so you need to be fairly sure that the costs outweigh the benefits before you switch, or switch a little bit at a time so that you can switch back if it doesn't work out. Again, testing helps.

Comment: 1. Optimising has been an ongoing struggle as our main perf-killing query is roughly 100 lines of SQL and very complex
2. Currently it is less than 64gb, and we have been scaling up, but that feels like a temporary solution
3. writing data as it appears and generating reports
4-5. possibly, however, I feel the problem lies in aggregation rather than data storage
6. Sharding might work, but what would happen to the aggregation queries in that use case?

Comment: 1. 100 lines seems pretty large, definitely try simplifying/caching this one first.  2. If you're scaling, most things are temporary solutions. Extra RAM might buy you more time and get you over the hump. 3. Generating/storing those reports (or parts of them) ahead of time might help. 4,5. Aggregation might get faster if the storage is "denser" 6. Best case, your workload is divided by N. You may need to spread heavy users out manually to achieve this in practice, though.

Answer (score 0):

If practical, do not store the massive amount of data at all!

Instead, summarize (aggregate) chunks of data as they arrive, then store the summaries.

Advantages:

- Perhaps one-tenth as much disk space needed;
- Reports are perhaps 10 times as fast,
- Can be done in the existing RDBMS.

Disadvantages:

- You cannot retrofit a different summarization.  (OK, you could keep the raw data and start over; this may be better anyway.)
- More code complexity.

[*Discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) of Summary Tables.